# Jquery dialog close button does not close; Dialog opens only once

Tags: jquery, struts2, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

This problem seems to be very common, and after researching and trying all the suggested solutions that have worked for others aren't working for me.  To add, firebug is not showing any errors as well.

I am using a Jquery modal dialog.  The dialog will be opened via link on a column of a grid.
The problem is it is opened only once, and the close button is not closing the dialog, however I am able to close it with the (X) on top right corner.  However, on trying to reopen a dialog for a different column value the dialog is not opened (the server side action class is executed though)..  Please help.

Relevant Code:
Parent Page (jsp)

```
 <s:url id="testurl" action="openView"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $("#dialogOne").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      title: 'Details',
      modal:true,
      width:970,
      buttons: { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
      open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show(); }
      });
```

});

```
 function formatLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                    return "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:openDialog("+cellvalue+");return false;'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
                                    }
                                function openDialog(number) {
                                    $("#dialogOne").load("<s:property value="testurl"/>?Number="+number);
                                    $("#dialogOne").dialog('open');
                                }
```

Relevant grid column:

```
 <sjg:gridColumn 
                                            name="number" 
                                            index="nsNumber" 
                                            title="View Action" 
                                            formatter="formatLink" 
                                            sortable="false" 
                                            width="80"

                                    />
```

I have tried the ajax solutions, and document ready suggested variations and it did not work.  The action openView returns a jsp and i have made sure that the div ids on that page are all unique, if that makes any difference.  Firebug does not show any errors.  Dialog opens only once, and cannot close through the dialog Close button. And, cannot open  (/reopen) dialog there after.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with your script configurations. The event handlers are not being initialized properly and so the events are not being executed as expected.

Generally you will want to initialize the pages when they load and I've had the greatest success with wrapping my handlers in a $(document).ready() function. Along with this, the onClick method you are using is also suspect. If you are using jQuery, it's best to avoid onClick assigned to the tag itself. By using jQuery and it's binding mechanisms, you can avoid issues where dynamic page elements are not functioning as expected in regards to event handlers.

```
 function formatLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
          return "<a href='#' class='dialogLink' data-cell='cellvalue'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
      }

 $(document).ready(Function(){

       $("#dialogOne").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Details',
            modal:true,
            width:970,
            buttons: { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show(); }
       });

       // This will bind the event handler to any link with this class. The data 
       // attribute is used to set/get the cellvalue from the link that is clicked.
       $('.dialogLink').on('click', function(){
            var number = $(this).data('cell');
            $("#dialogOne").load("<s:property value="testurl"/>?Number="+number);
            $("#dialogOne").dialog('open');
        });

  });
```